# After an automatic update on windows 8.1 pc is doing rolling restarts

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

I got a notification a few hours ago that windows 8.1 had installed an auto update that required a restart.  I decided to delay the restart.  Then, as I was doing a video chat session in Lync the Lync app crashed.  A few seconds later my PC restarted.  Now I cannot boot into windows 8.1. When I try the machine simply reboots at some point during bootup. My machine is configured to dual boot and I'm successfully using Windows 7.

So I believe a recent update has destroyed my system.  Anyone hear of a recent update causing PC crashing or have another suggestion?  I can still access the windows 8 HD which is a separate physical drive.

**Edit**
After nothing particularly different my system decided it was ok to boot into Windows 8.1.  The following updates were installed today:

[KB2868626](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=489dab1b-bca6-4525-b3f1-af3968d9f0d6)
[KB2900986](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=a7e57c92-62fa-4844-948e-31187fd48e81)
[KB2898108](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=8ed3df87-fb63-4cc3-93f6-736f1ff331b2)
[KB2888505](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=1a46803e-5c37-4765-923d-92d9512c7334)
[KB2876331](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=de87b8b9-bf36-4494-b0cf-3052d14ab20c)
[KB2862152](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=bac36bc2-6707-4805-8a2f-641697752e8a)

Evntvwr log shows Event ID 6008: "The previous system shutdown at 10:42:57 AM on ‎11/‎20/‎2013 was unexpected."

Comment: do you have a system restore point which you can use to restore Windows to a point before the update was installed?

Comment: After 2 failed boots you should be given a chance to boot into Safe Mode.  Are you able to access Safe Mode?  Which Boot Manager are you using, if properly configured, the Windows 8 Boot Manager should be selecting Windows 7.

Comment: I have not been given any safe mode options after many more than 2 failed boots.  I think i need to be able to acess safe mode to restore.  I will try F12? To force boot menu access.  Restarts are happening before the login menu

Comment: If your unable to boot into safe mode you cannot rule out possible conflicts with the update.  What updates were installed?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know what it installed.  This was done by auto update.  I don't know of any way to check because I can't get into the OS.